# String Handeling Problem while Printing max/min code point of character

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to print the max & min code point value of character in each word of String.

```
char max=' ', min='z';
int word=1;
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {     
  for(int j=0;j<s[i].length;j++) {
    if(s[i].charAt(j)<min)
      min=s[i].charAt(j);

    if(s[i].charAt(j)>max)
      max=s[i].charAt(j);
  }
  System.out.println("CHARACTER WITH MAX & MIN CODE POINT VALUE  IN WORD "+word +"IS: "+ max + min);
  word++;
}
}
```

It's having the following error in the 5th line:

> `variable.length` can't provide actual value.

What is the root cause for that error message?

Comment: Should be: `s[i].length()`. You're missing the parentheses at the end of the **String#length()** method. Just  `length` is for arrays not strings. **s[i]** contains a string element from the array **s** at index **i**.

Answer (score 0):

The line 4th code should be: `for(int j=0;j<s[i].length();j++) {`

- `.length` is the attribute for Array.
- `[].length` attribute can get the number of objects in Array.
- `.length()` is the function for String.
- `String.length()` function can get the number of characters in String.

Comment: I removed the link. It has no place in answers. You can include it on your user profile about me page if you like.